# pp.x command in quantum espresso

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am trying to generate the .pp and .cube file using pp.x -i (input file name) command. But, the .cube file is not getting generated and the output.log file also shows an error message.
this is my pp.x input file:
&INPUTPP
prefix='cspbi3'
outdir='relax-bulk'
filplot='CsPbI3_pristine.pp'
plot_num=11
/
&PLOT
nfile=1
filepp(1)='CsPbI3_pristine.pp'
iflag=3
output_format=6
filout='pristine_cspbi3.cube'
/

this is the error message which i get when i run the pp.x command:
Calling punch_plot, plot_num =  11
Writing data to file  CsPbI3_pristine.pp
Message from routine chdens:
namelist plot not found or invalid, exiting
Please help me someone. Its urgent. [image: pp.x input file below]